# Error Building Clang/LLVM with CyGIN: CLANG_TABLEGEN_EXE not set

Tags: build, cygwin, clang, llvm

I'm trying to get llvm/clang built on my Windows 10 box under CYGWIN. I've been working on this for a bit and have resolved many of the errors myself, but now I'm hitting one that I can't find any resources on. I get an error that says CLANG_TABLEGEN_EXE not set. Below is the full output from a fresh build. Any help is much appreciated.

```
C:\cygwin64\usr\src\llvm-build>cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm
-- No build type selected, default to Debug
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for dirent.h
-- Looking for dirent.h - found
-- Looking for dlfcn.h
-- Looking for dlfcn.h - found
-- Looking for errno.h
-- Looking for errno.h - found
-- Looking for execinfo.h
-- Looking for execinfo.h - not found
-- Looking for fcntl.h
-- Looking for fcntl.h - found
-- Looking for inttypes.h
-- Looking for inttypes.h - found
-- Looking for limits.h
-- Looking for limits.h - found
-- Looking for link.h
-- Looking for link.h - not found
-- Looking for malloc.h
-- Looking for malloc.h - found
-- Looking for malloc/malloc.h
-- Looking for malloc/malloc.h - not found
-- Looking for ndir.h
-- Looking for ndir.h - not found
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for signal.h
-- Looking for signal.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for sys/dir.h
-- Looking for sys/dir.h - found
-- Looking for sys/ioctl.h
-- Looking for sys/ioctl.h - found
-- Looking for sys/mman.h
-- Looking for sys/mman.h - found
-- Looking for sys/ndir.h
-- Looking for sys/ndir.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/param.h
-- Looking for sys/param.h - found
-- Looking for sys/resource.h
-- Looking for sys/resource.h - found
-- Looking for sys/stat.h
-- Looking for sys/stat.h - found
-- Looking for sys/time.h
-- Looking for sys/time.h - found
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for sys/uio.h
-- Looking for sys/uio.h - found
-- Looking for termios.h
-- Looking for termios.h - found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - found
-- Looking for utime.h
-- Looking for utime.h - found
-- Looking for valgrind/valgrind.h
-- Looking for valgrind/valgrind.h - not found
-- Looking for zlib.h
-- Looking for zlib.h - not found
-- Looking for fenv.h
-- Looking for fenv.h - found
-- Looking for FE_ALL_EXCEPT
-- Looking for FE_ALL_EXCEPT - found
-- Looking for FE_INEXACT
-- Looking for FE_INEXACT - found
-- Looking for mach/mach.h
-- Looking for mach/mach.h - not found
-- Looking for mach-o/dyld.h
-- Looking for mach-o/dyld.h - not found
-- Looking for histedit.h
-- Looking for histedit.h - not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXXABI_H
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXXABI_H - Success
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Looking for pthread_getspecific in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_getspecific in pthread - found
-- Looking for pthread_rwlock_init in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_rwlock_init in pthread - found
-- Looking for pthread_mutex_lock in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_mutex_lock in pthread - found
-- Looking for dlopen in dl
-- Looking for dlopen in dl - found
-- Looking for clock_gettime in rt
-- Looking for clock_gettime in rt - found
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Looking for compress2 in z
-- Looking for compress2 in z - not found
-- Looking for setupterm in tinfo
-- Looking for setupterm in tinfo - not found
-- Looking for setupterm in terminfo
-- Looking for setupterm in terminfo - not found
-- Looking for setupterm in curses
-- Looking for setupterm in curses - not found
-- Looking for setupterm in ncurses
-- Looking for setupterm in ncurses - not found
-- Looking for setupterm in ncursesw
-- Looking for setupterm in ncursesw - not found
-- Looking for xar_open in xar
-- Looking for xar_open in xar - not found
-- Looking for arc4random
-- Looking for arc4random - found
-- Looking for backtrace
-- Looking for backtrace - not found
-- Looking for _Unwind_Backtrace
-- Looking for _Unwind_Backtrace - found
-- Looking for getpagesize
-- Looking for getpagesize - found
-- Looking for getrusage
-- Looking for getrusage - found
-- Looking for setrlimit
-- Looking for setrlimit - found
-- Looking for isatty
-- Looking for isatty - found
-- Looking for futimens
-- Looking for futimens - found
-- Looking for futimes
-- Looking for futimes - found
-- Looking for sigaltstack
-- Looking for sigaltstack - found
-- Looking for writev
-- Looking for writev - found
-- Looking for mallctl
-- Looking for mallctl - not found
-- Looking for mallinfo
-- Looking for mallinfo - found
-- Looking for malloc_zone_statistics
-- Looking for malloc_zone_statistics - not found
-- Looking for mkdtemp
-- Looking for mkdtemp - found
-- Looking for mkstemp
-- Looking for mkstemp - found
-- Looking for mktemp
-- Looking for mktemp - found
-- Looking for closedir
-- Looking for closedir - found
-- Looking for opendir
-- Looking for opendir - found
-- Looking for readdir
-- Looking for readdir - found
-- Looking for getcwd
-- Looking for getcwd - found
-- Looking for gettimeofday
-- Looking for gettimeofday - found
-- Looking for getrlimit
-- Looking for getrlimit - found
-- Looking for posix_spawn
-- Looking for posix_spawn - found
-- Looking for pread
-- Looking for pread - found
-- Looking for realpath
-- Looking for realpath - found
-- Looking for sbrk
-- Looking for sbrk - found
-- Looking for srand48
-- Looking for srand48 - found
-- Looking for lrand48
-- Looking for lrand48 - found
-- Looking for drand48
-- Looking for drand48 - found
-- Looking for strtoll
-- Looking for strtoll - found
-- Looking for strtoq
-- Looking for strtoq - not found
-- Looking for strerror
-- Looking for strerror - found
-- Looking for strerror_r
-- Looking for strerror_r - found
-- Looking for strerror_s
-- Looking for strerror_s - not found
-- Looking for setenv
-- Looking for setenv - found
-- Looking for dlerror
-- Looking for dlerror - found
-- Looking for dlopen
-- Looking for dlopen - found
-- Looking for __GLIBC__
-- Looking for __GLIBC__ - not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_INT64_T
-- Performing Test HAVE_INT64_T - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_UINT64_T
-- Performing Test HAVE_UINT64_T - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_U_INT64_T
-- Performing Test HAVE_U_INT64_T - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS_WITHOUT_LIB
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS_WITHOUT_LIB - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS64_WITHOUT_LIB
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS64_WITHOUT_LIB - Success
-- Performing Test LLVM_HAS_ATOMICS
-- Performing Test LLVM_HAS_ATOMICS - Success
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_NO_VARIADIC_MACROS_FLAG
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_NO_VARIADIC_MACROS_FLAG - Success
-- Performing Test HAS_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAS_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Target triple: x86_64-unknown-cygwin
-- Native target architecture is X86
-- Threads enabled.
-- Doxygen disabled.
-- Sphinx disabled.
-- Go bindings disabled.
-- Could NOT find OCaml (missing:  OCAMLFIND OCAML_VERSION OCAML_STDLIB_PATH)
-- Could NOT find OCaml (missing:  OCAMLFIND OCAML_VERSION OCAML_STDLIB_PATH)
-- OCaml bindings disabled.
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_MISSING_FIELD_INITIALIZERS_FLAG
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_MISSING_FIELD_INITIALIZERS_FLAG - Success
-- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_COVERED_SWITCH_DEFAULT_FLAG
-- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_COVERED_SWITCH_DEFAULT_FLAG - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_COVERED_SWITCH_DEFAULT_FLAG
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_COVERED_SWITCH_DEFAULT_FLAG - Failed
-- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR_FLAG
-- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR_FLAG - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR_FLAG
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR_FLAG - Success
-- Performing Test C_WCOMMENT_ALLOWS_LINE_WRAP
-- Performing Test C_WCOMMENT_ALLOWS_LINE_WRAP - Failed
-- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_WERROR_DATE_TIME
-- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_WERROR_DATE_TIME - Success
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_WERROR_DATE_TIME
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_WERROR_DATE_TIME - Success
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_CXX11
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_CXX11 - Success
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3.6 (found version "3.6.1")
-- Constructing LLVMBuild project information
-- LLVMHello ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- Targeting AArch64
-- Targeting AMDGPU
-- Targeting ARM
-- Targeting BPF
-- Targeting Hexagon
-- Targeting Mips
-- Targeting MSP430
-- Targeting NVPTX
-- Targeting PowerPC
-- Targeting Sparc
-- Targeting SystemZ
-- Targeting X86
-- Targeting XCore
-- Clang version: 3.9.1
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_NO_NESTED_ANON_TYPES_FLAG
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_NO_NESTED_ANON_TYPES_FLAG - Failed
-- BugpointPasses ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- SampleAnalyzerPlugin ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- PrintFunctionNames ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- AnnotateFunctions ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
CMake Error at cmake/modules/TableGen.cmake:13 (message):
  CLANG_TABLEGEN_EXE not set
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  tools/clang/cmake/modules/AddClang.cmake:21 (tablegen)
  tools/include/clang/AST/CMakeLists.txt:1 (clang_tablegen)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/usr/src/llvm-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/usr/src/llvm-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I noticed that under tools/include - the cgywin version of the llvm source already includes clang. As such, I scrapped my modified directory - for I had followed the instructions on the llvm website of getting the clang source code and putting it under tools/clang.

After restoring the unmodified llvm source code, I was able to finally get cmake to work!